# Double click on table row and insert value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use this code to double click on table row and insert a value into input filed:

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/......iv[3]"));
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.doubleClick(element).perform();
    
            Thread.sleep(3000);
    
            // Insert into Accessorial Tasks screen Actual value
            insertInputFieldByXPath(driver, "...../input",
                    "3");

protected void insertInputFieldByXPath(WebDriver driver, String input_id, String value){
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(input_id)));
        webElement.clear();  // First we delete the old value in case if this is a spinner
        webElement.sendKeys(value);
    }
```

When I double click with Selenium the table row becomes input field. But when I try to enter some value the id is not found. Maybe it's not found because the input field ID is dynamically added when I double click.

Do you know how this issue can be solved?

Comment: I guess the element is changed by the double click. So if you could share with us the web page we could see it.

Comment: 1. Define is input field becomes different. 2 If possible share html so it will be easier to answer.